# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 81201: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, runtime-error

I am trying to read a dictionary_format_file.txt but I keep getting the error at line.

I read other posts and they made complete sense, however I could not fix my problem still.

Any help is appreciated.

```
import ast

path = '/Users/xyz/Desktop/final/'
filename = 'dictionary_format_text_file.txt'

with open((path+filename), 'r') as f:
    s=f.read()
    s=s.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
```

Error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xyz/Desktop/final/boolean_query.py", line 347, in <module>
    s=s.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
builtins.UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 81201: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20)

Comment: Apparently you didn't search very hard. @DYZ and I both found it within 4 minutes of your post.

Comment: Side-note: You used a `with` statement, so calling `f.close()` is redundant/wrong. The whole point of the `with` statement is that it guarantees resources are freed when the block is exited.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Understood. Thank you.

Comment: @DYZ I did look over that example but I am not sure how to use that to solve my problem. I am not using the str() function

Comment: `literal_eval` uses `str()`, so, same difference.

Comment: @DYZ  ' yourstring = yourstring.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')' . I tried using this but it keeps giving me the same error at this line. DYZ could you possibly tell me how to fix it?

Comment: Firstly, what is it in you file that causes the error? Do you know what non-ASCII symbols are in the file?

Comment: `literal_eval` is trying to decode the bytes you read from the file since you didn't provide Unicode. Open the file with `codecs.open` and provide the proper encoding parameter.

Comment: The file is a dictionary_format.txt file. ' {....}. The file was written using ' file=("file_name",'w'). So I dont think so that there would be any non-ascii characters. Also this error is only occuring on my macintosh machine and not on linux desktop.

Comment: P.S. it's much more useful to see the whole verbose stack trace than to just see the one line. Please try to edit that into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`f.read` is returning a byte string, not a Unicode string. When you try to use `encode` on it, Python 2 tries to decode it first using the `'ascii'` codec with errors turned on (Python 3 would simply give you an error without trying to decode). It's that hidden `decode` that is generating the error. You can easily avoid it by getting rid of the redundant `encode`:

```
s=s.decode('ascii', 'ignore')
```